# Can't connect to internet from host when QEMU/KVM guest is on with virtual network

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, internet-connection, linux-kvm

I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 on a Dell Inspiron 1545.
When I try to access a website, sometimes it shows a "Server not found"(Firefox), but sometimes it just never finishes looking up the server.
But I can access the Internet from VM/guest.
I can, however, access the Internet from host when the network setup method is Wicked service but not when the network setup method is NetworkManager. After I shut down the virtual machine, the Internet connection from host works fine.
What is the issue? Looked at the Firewall, but I didn't notice any problem with that(not that there isn't). Couldn't find the log file for the Network connections(looked in /var/log but didn't know which was the log I wanted).

Comment: Only happens when I use a routed virtual network.

Answer (score 0):

same issue on Fedora 25, using Virtual Machine Manager.

However in my case, I am connected to the internet, and can access webpages by IP address, and connect to remote hosts via IP and port. It just seems that no answers to DNS queries are occurring, even though the DNS is specified correctly and have even tried different DNSs. It is worth noting that this issue happens both when the virtual machine is running and when it is shut off.

To research this issue, I am connected via RDP to a remote machine, and browsing via the remote machine's browser as I cannot browse locally since my virtual machine is an instance of RouterOS by Microtik and has no GUI other than the http portal for management of the router functions, which is accessible from the Host machine via the 'default' virtual NAT interface, virbr0